# ArcGIS spatial query returned wrong count and ID list

Tags: arcgis-server, spatial-query

I am currently encountering a very perplexing issue:

- I have an ArcGIS feature layer of polygons
- I am trying to query if any polygons in the feature contains a specific point
- When I call the API to ask for the whole feature (`returnGeometry: false`, `where: 1=1`, `geometryType: esriGeometryPoint`, `spatialRel: esriSpatialRelWithin`) it works fine
- When I call the API to ask for feature counts (`returnCountOnly: true`) or feature ID only (`returnIdsOnly: true`) it works for most cases; but there are some places where the query returns 0 counts, no feature IDs but 1 feature.
- When I take note of the specific feature's Object ID and query it directly (`objectIds: {objectId}`), all 3 returned results are consistent

Is returned feature count and ID list unreliable like this? Do I really have to ask for whole features just to get the correct result? It seems to me it shouldn't behave this way, and I cannot find any mentions of others encountering similar issue.